# C# ActiveDirectory - How do I add a local user account remotely from a domain-joined machine to a non-domain machine

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to add a local user account on a non-domain joined machine. I have tried just about everything I can think of. I have this working on machines in the same domain, but not on off-domain machines. I can ping and TS to this server, but can't seem to add an admin.

Is it possible to use DirectoryEntry to do this?

Here's the code I currently have (slightly altered for readability):

```
    private string AddLocalAdmin_NonDomain(string ComputerName)
    {
        StartImpersonation(); //Uses advapi32.dll->LogonUser()
        string ErrMsg = "";
        const int ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000;
        DirectoryEntry AD = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + ComputerName + ",computer", ComputerName + "\\" + UserCredentials.Username, UserCredentials.Password);
        object n = AD.NativeObject;
        DirectoryEntry NewUser = AD.Children.Add(Username, "user");
        NewUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { Password });
        if (!PasswordExpires)
        {
            int val = ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD;
            NewUser.InvokeSet("userFlags", new object[] { val });
        }
        NewUser.CommitChanges();
        DirectoryEntry grp;
        grp = AD.Children.Find("Administrators", "group");
        if (grp != null) { grp.Invoke("Add", new object[] { NewUser.Path.ToString() }); }
        EndImpersonation(); //Ends the impersonation
        return ErrMsg; //returns "Access Denied"
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
```

and to achive that here is the code

```
PrincipalContext oPrincipalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine);

//Create New User
UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(oPrincipalContext, "Your UserName", "Your Password", true /*Enabled or not*/);

oUserPrincipal.UserPrincipalName = "Your UserName";
oUserPrincipal.GivenName = "Given Name";
oUserPrincipal.Surname = "Surname";
oUserPrincipal.Save();

//Add User to Group
GroupPrincipal oGroupPrincipal = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(oPrincipalContext, "Your Group Name");
oGroupPrincipal.Members.Add(oUserPrincipal);
oGroupPrincipal.Save();
```

for a full implementation go here http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/active-directory-c/

Comment: Thanks for the response. That method is much nicer than my ASDI query. Unfortunately, this method works on machines on the same domain, but not on unjoined machines. I tried passing credentials into the oPrincipalContext as well as using the LogonUser method. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry I cant quite get your response, do you mean that you query users on the local machine only with out a domain?

Comment: Sorry. Let me clarify what I'm trying to do: I want to Add an admin remotely from my desktop DESK1 (on domain XDEV) to SERVER1 (no domain at all) using this app.
I can add to any machine on the same domain that I have an admin account on. I can also impersonate another account (ie. TECHADMIN) that is a local admin on that machine. The trouble is when I need to add a user on a non-domain machine from an on-domain machine. I'm not really 100% sure its possible.
I can use psexec, but I was hoping to use AD directly since its a bit cleaner. Does that make sense?